# Python Typing: Type literal

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing

I am writing a function that takes an argument `dtype` of type `type` as shown below.

```py
def my_function(dtype: type):
    pass
```

Is there a way to restrict **the value of** `dtype` only to `str` and `int`? The type union `str | int` will not do the job because it will then be interpreted as `dtype` can have a value **with type** `str` or `int`, which is not the case.

Also, I may not want to assert the value of `dtype` because `mypy` doesn't seem to work well with it.

```py
def my_function(dtype: type):
    assert dtype == str or dtype == int
```

Is there a workaround to this problem?

Comment: I believe you want want `type[int] | type[str]` (on Python 3.10+), or on 3.9, `typing.Union[type[str], type[int]]`, or earlier versions, `typing.Union[typing.Type[int], typing.Type[str]]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I'm going to post the answer for future reference. Big thank you to  [juanpa.arrivillaga](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5014455/juanpa-arrivillaga) for the solution!

We [can use](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/kinds_of_types.html#the-type-of-class-objects) the generic [`Type[T]`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Type) from the `typing` module to refer to a literal type, as shown below.

```py
from typing import Type


def my_function(dtype: Type[str] | Type[int]):
    pass
```

Or from **Python 3.9**, `builtins.type` now supports the `type[T]` generic, as stated in [**PEP 585**](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0585/).

```py
def my_function(dtype: type[str] | type[int]):
    pass
```

Comment: Note also that `type[int] | type[str]` and `type[int | str]` are equivalent (ditto for the older syntax using `typing.Union`)